# Combinatorics neighboured groups

Tags: combinatorics

I was wondering whether there are is a specific class of combinatorics that deals with grouped scenarios. I have a set of data that is ordered into groups and you cannot move the groups about only merge them into neighboring groups - they can be merged into multiple neighbors - although the last group cannot be merged into the first group.

For example, I am interested in how many ways you can combine 24 into 200 groups - but only if they are neighbouring groups. The classic $nCr$ approach would generate too many values.